# How can I scale android xy plot?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in Android and I try to scale the chart in my application, but the code I wrote below doesn't work due to error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method (android.view.View$OnTouchListener)' on a null object reference.
```

I have no idea, how I could correct it in my code.

Thank in advance for help.

```
    public class EcgChartActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
    {


 private PointF minXY;
 private PointF maxXY;

//Class updating the data on the chart
private class EcgUpdater implements Observer {
    private final Plot plot;

    public EcgUpdater(Plot plot) {
        this.plot = plot;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
        plot.redraw();
    }
}

private XYPlot ecgPlot;
private EcgUpdater ecgUpdater;
private Thread ecgPlotThread;
private LinkedHashMap<Integer, ChannelData> allChannelsData;
private EcgDataSource ecgDataSource;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ecg_chart);


    this.ecgPlot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.ecg_plot);

    this.ecgUpdater = new EcgUpdater(this.ecgPlot);

    this.ecgDataSource = BaseApp.getApp().getEcgDataSource();

    this.ecgPlotThread = new Thread(this.ecgDataSource);

    ecgPlot.setOnTouchListener(this);



     ecgPlot.getGraphWidget().setTicksPerRangeLabel(1);
     ecgPlot.getGraphWidget().setTicksPerDomainLabel(1);
     ecgPlot.getGraphWidget().setRangeValueFormat(
            new DecimalFormat("#######"));
    ecgPlot.getGraphWidget().setDomainValueFormat(
            new DecimalFormat("#######"));
    ecgPlot.getGraphWidget().setRangeLabelWidth(25);
    ecgPlot.setRangeLabel("");
    ecgPlot.setDomainLabel("");

    //Adding series to chart

    EcgPlotSeries channel1 = new EcgPlotSeries(this.ecgDataSource, 0, "Channel 1", Color.RED);
    this.ecgPlot.addSeries(channel1, channel1.getFormatter());

    EcgPlotSeries channel2 = new EcgPlotSeries(this.ecgDataSource, 1, "Channel 2", Color.BLUE);
    this.ecgPlot.addSeries(channel2, channel2.getFormatter());

    ecgPlot.redraw();
    ecgPlot.calculateMinMaxVals();
    minXY=new PointF(ecgPlot.getCalculatedMinX().floatValue(),ecgPlot.getCalculatedMinY().floatValue());
    maxXY=new PointF(ecgPlot.getCalculatedMaxX().floatValue(),ecgPlot.getCalculatedMaxY().floatValue());


    BaseApp.getApp().getEcgDataSource().addObserver(this.ecgUpdater);      

}


// Definition of the touch states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int ONE_FINGER_DRAG = 1;
static final int TWO_FINGERS_DRAG = 2;
int mode = NONE;

PointF firstFinger;
float lastScrolling;
float distBetweenFingers;
float lastZooming;


@Override
public void onResume() {
    // Uruchomienie wątku rysującego wykres
    this.ecgPlotThread.start();
    super.onResume();
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    BaseApp.getApp().getEcgDataSource().stopThread();
    super.onPause();
}



@Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           firstFinger = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
           mode = ONE_FINGER_DRAG;
           break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
           break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
           Timer t = new Timer();
               t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                   public void run() {
                       while(Math.abs(lastScrolling)>1f || Math.abs(lastZooming-1)<1.01){ 
                       lastScrolling*=.8;
                       scroll(lastScrolling);
                       lastZooming+=(1-lastZooming)*.2;
                       zoom(lastZooming);
                       ecgPlot.setDomainBoundaries(minXY.x, maxXY.x, BoundaryMode.AUTO);
                       ecgPlot.redraw();
                   }
                   }


             }, 0);

             break;  

       case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: 
           distBetweenFingers = spacing(event);
           if (distBetweenFingers > 5f) {
               mode = TWO_FINGERS_DRAG;
           }
           break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
           if (mode == ONE_FINGER_DRAG) {
               PointF oldFirstFinger=firstFinger;
               firstFinger=new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
               lastScrolling=oldFirstFinger.x-firstFinger.x;
               scroll(lastScrolling);
               lastZooming=(firstFinger.y-oldFirstFinger.y)/ecgPlot.getHeight();
               if (lastZooming<0)
                   lastZooming=1/(1-lastZooming);
               else
                   lastZooming+=1;
               zoom(lastZooming);
               ecgPlot.setDomainBoundaries(minXY.x, maxXY.x, BoundaryMode.AUTO);
               ecgPlot.redraw();

           } else if (mode == TWO_FINGERS_DRAG) {
               float oldDist =distBetweenFingers; 
               distBetweenFingers=spacing(event);
               lastZooming=oldDist/distBetweenFingers;
               zoom(lastZooming);
               ecgPlot.setDomainBoundaries(minXY.x, maxXY.x, BoundaryMode.AUTO);
               ecgPlot.redraw();
           }
           break;
       }
       return true;

    }

    private void zoom(float scale) {
        float domainSpan = maxXY.x - minXY.x;
        float domainMidPoint = maxXY.x - domainSpan / 2.0f;
        float offset = domainSpan * scale / 2.0f;
        minXY.x=domainMidPoint- offset;
        maxXY.x=domainMidPoint+offset;
    }

    private void scroll(float pan) {
        float domainSpan = maxXY.x - minXY.x;
        float step = domainSpan / ecgPlot.getWidth();
        float offset = pan * step;
        minXY.x+= offset;
        maxXY.x+= offset;
    }

    @SuppressLint("FloatMath")
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }
```

}

**Log:**

```
12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137): java.lang.RuntimeException:     Unable to start activity      ComponentInfo{com.example.ecganalyzer/com.example.ecganalyzer.activities.EcgChartActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot.setOnTouchListener(android.view.View$OnTouchListener)' on a null object reference
12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137):at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot.setOnTouchListener(android.view.View$OnTouchListener)' on a null object reference
12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137): at com.example.ecganalyzer.activities.EcgChartActivity.onCreate(EcgChartActivity.java:112)12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020) 12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)12-09 21:39:40.893: E/AndroidRuntime(3137):    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The crash happens on this line:

```
ecgPlot.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

It is because the 'ecgPlot' variable is null.

It is set on the line

```
this.ecgPlot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.ecg_plot);
```

Check your 'R.layout.activity_ecg_chart' file.
Looks like it doesn't have the view with id 'R.id.ecg_plot'

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I checked the layout and actually had a mistake that you wrote. I corrected and started again but new errors occurred. I do not know, how I could fix them. I'll be grateful for your help.

Comment: This is my new errors:                                                                                 `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range and at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)  android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:1983) `

Comment: You have problems with handling multitouch. I don't have enough experience with that to help you.

Also, this error should be asked in another question, but I suggest first read more examples of how to work with multitouch.